# System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, db2, odbc

Can someone please look into this and help me out..................

---

I recently developed a VB.NET utility for extracting data from a DB2 table and populating an HTML report format. I am using ISeries ODBC provider for connection. The utility seems to be working fine for most users.

For some users, apparently the ones without admin privileges on their systems, this fails to work. The users are getting the below error:

> System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace threw an exception

The error occurs on the `connection.Open` line of the DB connection section.

```
Dim cn = New OdbcConnection("DSN=dsnname;UID=user;PWD=pswd")
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(qry, cn)
cn.Open() ' here
```

Is there any way to resolve this without granting admin privilege to the users?

Comment: can someone please respond to this.... i need some ideas as to why i am getting the exception..... pls help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509581/the-type-initializer-for-system-transactions-diagnostics-diagnostictrace-threw

Answer (score 1):

There was something wrong with my App.Config file.

I deleted it and added a new one from a new project and it fixed it for me.