# The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception

Tags: c#, exception, ms-access, connection

I need help solving this error.
This is the error `{"The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception."}`

I am using Access database and Platform for build configuration is Any CPU.

Sometimes the code runs well and sometimes it suddenly throws this exception. There are many similar questions asked here but none of them is solving my error.

This is my connection string

```
DbPath = @"d:\Ek.mdb";
ConnectionString =@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+DbPath+";User Id=admin;Password=;";
```

This is my function to open the connection
I am getting the error on `Con.Open()`

```
public bool OpenConnection()
        {
            if (Con == null)
            {
                Con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            }
            else if ((Con.State == ConnectionState.Broken || Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) && (Con.State!=ConnectionState.Open))
            {
                Con.Open();
                Tx = Con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
                return true;
            }
            else if (IsConnectionBusy())
            {
                throw new DataException("Connection Busy");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

This how I Close the connection after executing queries

```
public Boolean CloseConnection()
        {
            if(IsConnectionBusy())
                throw new DataException("Connection Busy");
            if (Con.State==ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Tx.Commit();
                Con.Close();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
public bool IsConnectionBusy()
    {
        switch (Con.State)
        {
            case ConnectionState.Connecting:
            case ConnectionState.Executing:
            case ConnectionState.Fetching:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I cannot find that why does it runs sometimes perfectly and then sometimes throws this exception. 

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have tried too much for solving this error but couldn't.
What I have noticed is at this line.

```
 else if ((Con.State == ConnectionState.Broken || Con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) && (Con.State!=ConnectionState.Open))
```

The connection is in `closed state`. When it is executing the `Con.Open()` statement the `Connection` state changes to `Open` and after that this error is thrown.

Also while debugging the error is not caused. It is only caused when I don't put a `breakpoint` at that place.

At `Con.Open()` when I put a breakpoint and stop there for a few seconds only for the first time then there is no error thrown. After that if I disable the breakpoint and no error is thrown...!!!

Comment: which MS office/access version are you using?

Comment: I am using 2007 and I have created the database for 2000-2003 compatible

Comment: Also I am not getting error if I put a breakpoint. It is only caused when there is no breakpoint and that too the error is not caused always.

Comment: I am guessing your office is 32bit version. if so please try to build your program in x86 mode. it may solve your problem. don't build in Any CPU.

Comment: I tried building on x86 mode but the same error still occurs.

Comment: At Con.Open() when I put a breakpoint and stop there for a few seconds only for the first time then there is no error thrown. After that if I disable the breakpoint and no error is thrown...!!!

Comment: Can you build a release build so that you get line numbers? Then you'll be able to see which line within CloseConnection is failing. I'm slightly concerned that all of this code is apparently happening in the DiagnosticTrace type initializer though...

Comment: `Db.dll!Db.DbOperations.OpenConnection() Line 202
Db.dll!Db.DbOperations.GetDataSet(string sql = "SELECT * FROM Emp") Line 175 + 0x9 bytes`

`EkMaidLib.dll!EkMaidLib.Emp.GetDataSetEmp() Line 119 + 0xc bytes`
`EKMaidAjency.exe!EKMaidAjency.Employer.FillDataGridEmp() Line 87 + 0x1d bytes`
`EKMaidAjency.exe!EKMaidAjency.Employer.Employer() Line 18`

Comment: `EKMaidAjency.exe!EKMaidAjency.Main.employerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender = {System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 38 + 0x15 bytes
`
`EKMaidAjency.exe!EKMaidAjency.Program.Main() Line 20`

Comment: @JonSkeet Were you asking for this information?

Comment: @coding: Well not quite... because it's `CloseConnection` that appears to be failing as per your question. Where did the other stack trace come from? It's *really* unclear what's going on, to be honest. Please update your question with full stack traces (not just the inner exception, but *everything) ideally with line numbers.

Comment: So where does "The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' threw an exception" come into it? And why don't you have any line numbers in that stack trace?

Comment: I have copied it from call stack..is it the same as stack trace..or different?
The line numbers in it are shown at the end of the statements.

And the line numbers are not present in the error which I copied from the error dialog. @JonSkeet

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added more info at the end of the question.

Comment: There are far too many errors here occurring at different times with different amounts of information to really be able to help you, I'm afraid. It's way too confused.

Comment: Can you suggest me that shifting the database to sqlite will help. @JonSkeet

Comment: No, almost certainly not. You need to get a handle on what's going on and why you have so many different errors reported in different ways first. I don't think we'll be able to help you with that...

Comment: No problem.. and Thank You very much for looking into details of the error. I will try to find some way and post the answer.

Comment: If you change in your app.config file then these type of error appears.
Change your app config settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the database to sqlite and everything is working very smoothly...
I think that in Access db there are some problems with the transactions.
It got resolved by changing the database. Still I am not sure what was causing that weird error.

Comment: This is just a workaround, obviously, it does not address the real issue.

Answer (score 3):

There was something wrong with my App.Config file.

I deleted it and added a new one from a new project and it fixed it for me.

Comment: This just worked in 2023 on a v2019 winform app

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out this exception's `InnerException` property.

I had this same error and, even though I was under unusual conditions, I thought it would still be useful to document the solution.

Context: simple console app needing to connect to MySql through the standard .NET connector ([MySql.Data](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data))

Context: the `connectionStrings` in my `app.config` was pointing to an external file by means of its `configSource` attribute. Now, in .NET you can point to an external config file only if that file is in the same directory or lower in the hierarchy, not higher. The point is, my external file was of course in a directory higher in the hierarchy, so I chose an alternate way to read the connection string I was interested in, and having resumed working on that app after a few days, I didn't remember that my `app.config` was broken.

That was the problem, apparently the connector (or some other ADO machinery) parses the `app.config` even when you don't access it programmatically, hence this error. I was able to figure it out because I looked at the InnerException, that's why I suggested inspecting it.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I found my problem to be in the config file as well (was playing the day before with log4net and how to set it up, was not working a 100% and moved on to another task, and was unable to simply connect to mysql db in a console app).

Answer (score 2):

I started getting this error on adding **appSettings** under **configuration** node which already had **configSections**.. 
InnerException stated that "Only one `configSections` element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root  element." So I just changed my config node sequence. My config looks like this now.

```
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup >
  <section name />
 </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
 <add key="xxx" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

**appSettings** has been moved after **configSections**. 
Although scenario seems to be different than the issue faced by the creator of this thread, Hope it helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use below two method to open and close the Access db connection and try to build the program in x86 mode and see if the problem arises:

```
OleDbConnection _oleCon;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _oleCon = new OleDbConnection();
        }

        bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                string DbPath = @"D:\Ek.mdb";
                _oleCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" + DbPath + ";";//ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbConnectionString"];
                _oleCon.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _oleCon.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: In all my previous projects in which I have used Access Db, I did not find any such issues. This was the first time I saw such behaviour.
The code runs perfectly well if I keep a breakpoint otherwise it gets an error.

Comment: I cannot try this code now because I have changed all the oledb variables to sqlite variables. Btw Thanks for the Code. I appreciate your help very much.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

remove empty space from app.config .....its working fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

I updated my NuGet packages which seemed to solve the issue for me connecting to a local SQLite database.